# How to write dynamic sheet reference in a googlesheet formula?

Tags: google-sheets

How to write dynamic sheet reference in a google sheets formula?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score -2):

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!A2:A100"),$L$16, INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!A2:A100"),$M$16)
```

```
Column H - I
Jan     <=31/01/2020 00:00:00   >31/12/2019 00:00:00
Column J - K
Feb     <=29/02/2020 00:00:00   >31/01/2020 00:00:00    
Column L - M
March   <=31/03/2020 00:00:00   >29/02/2020 00:00:00
```